# Update backbone View

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, intervals

I ve created a backbone model, which fetch json from a server. However, i want to update view with the new data, in specific time interval, not every time that the server sends data. What should i use with purpose to update backbone view every n milliseconds? I ve got the above code.

```
    $(function() {


    var Profile = Backbone.Model.extend();

    var ProfileList = Backbone.Collection.extend({

                    model: Profile,
                    url: 'data.php'
    });   

    var ProfileView = Backbone.View.extend({

        el: "#profiles",
        template: _.template($('#profileTemplate').html()),
        render: function(eventName) {

        _.each(this.model.models, function(profile){
        var profileTemplate = this.template(profile.toJSON());
        $(this.el).append(profileTemplate);
        }, this);

            return this;

        }
    });

        var profiles = new ProfileList();    
        var profilesView = new ProfileView({model: profiles});

        profiles.fetch({reset: true});
        //profiles.bind('reset', function () { console.log(profiles); });
        profiles.bind('reset', function () {
                profilesView.render();
        });

      });
```

Comment: Are you looking for a way to rerender your view every N ms without refreshing the data ? Or are you looking for a way to refresh the data (and then the view hosting it) every N ms ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *simple* solution would be:

```
profiles.fetch({reset: true});

setInterval(
  function() {
    profiles.fetch({reset: true});
  }, 1000 // Time in milliseconds
);
```

I wouldn't say that it's a beautiful solution but I hope you get the idea. As far as I know there is no interval fetch, or something similar, implemented in Backbone - so you pretty much have to build your own.

**EDIT**

This is probably a better solution, I like it more atleast.

```
var ProfileList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model   : Profile,
  url     : "data.php",
  xhr     : null,
  interval: null,

  fetchWithInterval: function(options) {
    var options = options || {},
        self    = this;

    this.interval = setInterval(function(){
      if(self.xhr !== null && self.xhr.readyState !== 4) {
        return;
      }
      self.xhr = self.constructor.__super__.fetch.apply(self, options);
    }, 1000);

    this.xhr = self.constructor.__super__.fetch.apply(self, options);
  },

  stopFetchWithInterval: function() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }
});
```

Use it with `profiles.fetchWithInterval({reset: true});` and you can stop it with `profiles.stopFetchWithInterval()`.

It also manages the `xhr`, so if the AJAX call isn't finished it will not start a new one. This is pretty handy if you want to fetch with a small interval or when your API is slow for some reason.

Comment: Ok this is what i want with a slighly difference. The above, creates multiple profileTemplate and as a result i ve got multiple divs one after other every 7sec.  How can I store every time one profileTemplate and change it? How can i change content and not append content??

Comment: I just change the append() with html() function and it works!!